# how can i get the path from NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-3, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

i want to get the path from downloadTask, how can i do that?

[setDownloadTaskDidWriteDataBlock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhFHa.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a legal way to access that value, without violating any `Private API policy of AppStore, but I highly recommend against using this as Apple usually change internal design of NSURLSession in each major version and this workaround can be broken at any time:

```
NSString *tmpPath = [task valueForKeyPath: @"downloadFile.path"];
```

or Swift:

```
let tmpPath = task.value(forKeyPath: "downloadFile.path") as? String
```